# Google App Script filtering Arrays based on Com

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the function below, I am trying to get the values of the **imported_Id** that are not present in the **old_Id** array, and store them them into a new array **add_IDs**. In the example below, I would want to store values **1004** and **1005** in a new array. I have tried using the filter() method and other variations of for loops but can't seem to  get it right. Any suggestions on a solutions would be greatly appreciated!

```
function myfunction() {
 
 const old_id = ["1000","1001","1002","1003"];
 const imported_id = ["1000","1001","1002","1003","1004","1005"];
  
 const add_ids = [];
  
 
  for(var x = 0; x < imported_id.length; x++){
    const append_id = [];
     for(var y = 0; y < old_id.length; y++) {
       if (old_id[y].indexOf(imported_id[x]) == -1){
        append_id.push(imported_id[x]);

       }
     }
    add_ids.push(append_id[x]);
  }
 
  
  Logger.log(add_ids);
}
```

Comment: A new post for new errors or follow up questions is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` and `array.includes()` to check if the number is in the second array

```js
const old_id = ["1000", "1001", "1002", "1003"];
const imported_id = ["1000", "1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005"];
res = imported_id.filter((n) => !old_id.includes(n));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

When your script is modified, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns. In this case, both patterns are the same result.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is a bit modified.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, I think that `append_id` can be used for checking the duplicate values.

  - For example, in this modification, when the duplicate values between `old_id` and `imported_id` are existing, the length of `append_id` is not `0`. This is used.
- By checking the length of `append_id`, the result value can be retrieved.

#### Modified script:

```js
const old_id = ["1000","1001","1002","1003"];
const imported_id = ["1000","1001","1002","1003","1004","1005"];
const add_ids = [];
for (var x = 0; x < imported_id.length; x++) {
  const append_id = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < old_id.length; y++) {
    if (old_id[y].indexOf(imported_id[x]) != -1) {  // or  if (old_id[y] == imported_id[x]) {
      append_id.push(imported_id[x]);
    }
  }
  if (append_id.length == 0) {
    add_ids.push(imported_id[x]);
  }
}
console.log(add_ids);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, "Array.prototype.indexOf()" is used instead of "String.prototype.indexOf()".

#### Modification point:

- When you use `indexOf`, by using "Array.prototype.indexOf()" index of "String.prototype.indexOf()", I think that inner for loop is not required.

#### Modified script:

```js
const old_id = ["1000","1001","1002","1003"];
const imported_id = ["1000","1001","1002","1003","1004","1005"];
const add_ids = [];
for (var x = 0; x < imported_id.length; x++) {
  if (old_id.indexOf(imported_id[x]) == -1) {
    add_ids.push(imported_id[x]);
  }
}
console.log(add_ids);
```

### References:

- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)